# The relation behind agent's velocity and [ forward] command in Netlogo?

Tags: controls, netlogo

I try to understand the meaning of a basic control theory problem.

To simulate the movement of an agent in netlogo we can use the forward command 
[fd speed]. 
this mean after a tick the turtle will move speed*patch.

In the case we add the dynamic for the turtle:

x'(t) = u(t)

In this case can we have some method to convert the value of x'(t) to fd?

Comment: So your agent has an attribute called speed with some value (eg 3). You have the code `forward speed`. It will move that many patches as you state in your question (in this case, it will move 3 patches). If you tell it to do this once per tick, then your velocity is 3 patches per tick (and technically you need a direction too for velocity). I am not clear what your question is.

Comment: For example, in rendezvous problem. You have n vector postion x[x1(t),x2(t),..,xn(t)]
If you have x'_i(t) = sum_j(x(j)-x(i)) (j in neighbour of J)
With this x'_i(t) is the velocity (continuous) version

But with netlogo we have only: x(t) =x(t-1) + fd (discrete version)
With this in my, I think that fd is not velocity anymore